# DateTimePicker in english

Tags: c#, winforms, internationalization

Using Visual Studio in Italian, in a project in Visual C# adding a form object DateTimePicker the calendar that is shown on the click, displays the months in the Italian language, as you can set the display in English?

Comment: As written in the duplicate, you can't do it :-(

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this is not possible with Microsoft's calendar control.

> This behavior occurs because the DateTimePicker control and the
>   MonthCalendar control are Microsoft Windows common controls.
>   Therefore, the operating system's user locale determines the user
>   interface of these controls.

https://support2.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb%3ben-us%3b889834&x=18&y=19

> To change this behavior, change the user locale calendar settings in
>   Control Panel. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Regional and Language Options.
> 2. In the Regional and Language Options dialog box, select an item in the Select an item to match its preferences, or click Customize to
>      choose your own format section to select the locale that you want the
>      control to use.
> 3. Click OK.

Comment: @CristianMagrini: I am sure it does. Where did you use this? Try to put this in the `Program.Main` method.

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work for DateTimePicker, the months still be in Italian

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

It just wraps the native calendar control, which uses the language of the operating system it runs on (but respecting a possibly installed OS language pack).

Comment: So I have to set the operating system language in English?

Comment: Yeah, with a language pack (not all Windows editions have that).